# Is there a way to get associated values based on 'Value' in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to java script. for example if I have an object,

```
var countryData = [{name :"India",[{state : "AP",capital:"vjw"}, {state:"TS",capital:"hyd"}] } {name :"Belgium",[{state : "AL",capital:"Montgomery"}, {state:"AK",capital:"Juneau"}] }]
```

Now I know the country & state value and I have to get its capital.

Comment: your inner array has no key.

Comment: Your JSON array is invalid

Comment: Learn how to iterate through arrays and objects and how to get key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a poper object with `states` properties, you could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
function getCapital(country, state) {
    return (countryData.find(c => c.name === country) || { states: [] })
        .states.find(s => s.state === state);
}

var countryData = [{ name: "India", states: [{ state: "AP", capital: "vjw" }, { state: "TS", capital: "hyd" }] }, { name: "Belgium", states: [{ state: "AL", capital: "Montgomery" }, { state: "AK", capital: "Juneau" }] }];

console.log(getCapital('Belgium', 'AL'));
console.log(countryData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First lets fix the data array

```
var countryData = [
    { name: "India", 'states': [
            { state: "AP", capital: "vjw" },
            { state: "TS", capital: "hyd" }
        ]
    },
    { name: "Belgium", 'states': [
            { state: "AL", capital: "Montgomery" },
            { state: "AK", capital: "Juneau" }
        ]
    }
];
```

Then you can iterate over this using array maps and simple conditions

```
 let stateCapital = '';

 countryData.map((country) => {
    if (country.name === 'India') {
        country.states.map((state) => {
            if (state.state === 'AP') {
                stateCapital = state.capital;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `map` returns a new array, you might use `some` and return `true` if found, for ending the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The object in your `countryData` is incorrect; see and test this code:

```
var countryData = [{name :"India","0":[{state : "AP",capital:"vjw"}, {state:"TS",capital:"hyd"}] }, {name :"Belgium","0":[{state : "AL",capital:"Montgomery"}, {state:"AK",capital:"Juneau"}] }];
var country ='India';
var state ='TS';
var capital ='';

for(var i=0; i<countryData.length; i++){
  if(countryData[i].name ==country){
    for(var i2=0; i2<countryData[i][0].length; i2++){
      if(countryData[i][0][i2].state ==state){
        capital = countryData[i][0][i2].capital;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
alert(capital);
```